# What is the correct string literal for python re.sub replacement?

Tags: python, regex

I don't understand the errors that I am getting with my python regex to insert Unicode characters into a regex substitution. Simplified examples are below.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) the repl parameter should be a `r''` string literal. But if I use a Unicode escape sequence for the replacement parameter then I get a `KeyError`. It's just fine to use that in the search pattern.

I'm looking to understand what this error message is telling me so I can better choose when to use `r''` vs `''` for the replacement pattern. Any help is appreciated.

```py
Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 09:23:15) 
[Clang 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Python shell history and tab completion are enabled.
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'"', r'\u201c', '"Quoted String"')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rgant/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-backend-09-_IN13/lib/python3.7/sre_parse.py", line 1021, in parse_template
    this = chr(ESCAPES[this][1])
KeyError: '\\u'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/rgant/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-backend-09-_IN13/lib/python3.7/re.py", line 192, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
  File "/Users/rgant/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-backend-09-_IN13/lib/python3.7/re.py", line 309, in _subx
    template = _compile_repl(template, pattern)
  File "/Users/rgant/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-backend-09-_IN13/lib/python3.7/re.py", line 300, in _compile_repl
    return sre_parse.parse_template(repl, pattern)
  File "/Users/rgant/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-backend-09-_IN13/lib/python3.7/sre_parse.py", line 1024, in parse_template
    raise s.error('bad escape %s' % this, len(this))
re.error: bad escape \u at position 0
>>> re.sub(r'"(.*)"', '\u201c\\1\u201d', '"Quoted String"')
'“Quoted String”'
>>> re.sub(r'"(.*)"', r'\1', '"Quoted String"')
'Quoted String'
>>> re.sub(r'\u201c', '!', '“Quoted String”')
'!Quoted String”'
>>> re.sub(r'\u201c(.*)\u201d', r'"\1"', '“Quoted String”')
'"Quoted String"'
>>> r'\u201c(.*)\u201d'
'\\u201c(.*)\\u201d'
>>> r'"\1"'
'"\\1"'
>>> r'\u201c'
'\\u201c'
>>> r'\u201c\1\u201d'
'\\u201c\\1\\u201d'
>>>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `r''` string makes backslashes be just backslashes.  So `r"\u201c"` has six characters: `\` `u` `2` `0` `1` `c`.  Then the regex engine looks at those characters and complains, "I don't know what backslash-u means!"

So this is a case where you want to not use an r-string for a regex substitution, because you need the backslash to introduce a unicode escape.  Without the r-prefix, you have a one-character string: `"\u201c"` has the character `\u201c`, or a curly quote.

As you showed, without the r-prefix, the substitution works properly:

```
>>> re.sub(r'"(.*)"', '\u201c\\1\u201d', '"Quoted String"')
'“Quoted String”'
```

Comment: You could also write out the actual characters `re.sub(r'"(.*)"', r'“\1”', '"Quoted String"')`

Comment: Ahh, I understand now. I thought the `r''` string literal was doing something more regex-y. Thanks!